# Loop notification to every user

Tags: php, arrays, function, loops

I'm trying to send a notification to every users thats assigned to a project.
I can get all user id by doing this

```
$ids = array_column($users, 'id');
    $userid = implode(', ', $ids);
    echo $userid;
```

But when I trying to put it insida my function nothing happened. It just blank.
I have also tried to move the "get user script" inside my function but still no luck.

**EDIT**

I also tried to manually write `$ids = array("14","1");` But I get the same error. But if I move it inside the function it works! If I do the same with `$ids = array_column($users, 'id');` the error is back

It works if I do this. But I want to get the users by automatic.

```
$ids = array(
  array(
    'id' => 1,
    'first_name' => 'Peter',
    'last_name' => 'Griffin',
  ),
  array(
    'id' => 14,
    'first_name' => 'Ben',
    'last_name' => 'Smith',
  ),
  array(
    'id' => 3,
    'first_name' => 'Joe',
    'last_name' => 'Doe',
  )
);


    foreach ($ids as $key => $user) {
        $um_notifications->api->store_notification( $user['id'], 'new_action', $vars );
   }
```

Here is the complete script, I hoped I have explained well.

```
<?php


    /* #### TEST OUTSIDE THE FUNCTION 'trigger_new_notification' #### 
        THIS WORKS AND PRINTING EX: '1, 8, 13'
    */ 
    $ids = array_column($users, 'id');
    $userid = implode(', ', $ids);
    echo $userid;



    /* #### NOTIFICATION 'trigger_new_notification' START #### */

    add_action('um_before_profile_fields', 'trigger_new_notification', 100);
    function trigger_new_notification( $args ) {
        global $um_notifications;


    /* Get information about the project */
    $vars = array(
        "post_title" => get_post_field( 'post_title', $project_id ),
        "photo" => um_get_avatar_url( get_avatar( get_current_user_id(), 40 ) ),
        "member" => um_user('display_name'),
        "notification_uri" => cpm_url_project_details( $project_id )
    );  

    /* Send notification to every assaigned user */
    foreach($ids as $row)
        {
            $um_notifications->api->store_notification( $row, 'new_action', $vars );
        }


     /* How it should print, where '14' is the user id */
    /* $um_notifications->api->store_notification( 14, 'new_action', $vars ); */


    }

    do_action( 'um_before_profile_fields');

    ?>
```

Comment: try `foreach($ids as $row)`

Comment: Did that, same result.. :-(

Comment: `$userid` is a string, you can't foreach a string.

Comment: But I also tried foreach($ids as $row)

Comment: The code you have now should work. It should print a line similar to what is below your loop commented. Just to be sure, can you var_dump $ids and paste it here?

Comment: This is what I get array(3) { [0]=> int(14) [1]=> int(3) [2]=> int(1) } It should work.. but it don't.. :-(

Comment: @Andreas I also tried to manually write `$ids = array("14","1");`
But I get the same error.
But if I move it inside the function it works!

If I do the same with  `$ids = array_column($users, 'id');` the error is back

Comment: @Andreas if I var_dump $ids when I move it inside the function, I get NULL.
But if I var_dump when it's outside I get the correct value

Comment: I have not even noticed there was a function. The unindented code made it easy to miss it.

Comment: @Andreas okay, Do you know what the problem can be?
Do I have to print results in any other way when it's in a function?
Tack för hjälpen! ☺️

Comment: I can't see where you call the function. You have `function trigger_new_notification( $args ) {` but you don't use $args in the function. What is $args? At some point you must call the function can you add $ids to the variables and add it in function declaration too: `function trigger_new_notification( $args, $ids ) {` That way your foreach loop will have something to work with.

Comment: @Andreas Se my Answer below ☺️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From some trial and error the solution was found.

Not sure what is the single point that made it work but the changes that was made is:
Added a functioncall
Added $ids to the functioncall
Added $ids to the function declaration

Still not sure what $args is but I left it there.

```
$ids = array_column($users, 'id'); // get IDs of users
add_action('um_before_profile_fields', 'trigger_new_notification', 100); 

function trigger_new_notification( $args , $ids ) {
    global $um_notifications;
    $vars = array(
        "post_title" => get_post_field( 'post_title', $project_id ),
        "photo" => um_get_avatar_url( get_avatar( get_current_user_id(), 40 ) ),
        "member" => um_user('display_name'),
        "notification_uri" => cpm_url_project_details( $project_id )
    );
    foreach($ids as $row){ // iterate the userIDs
            $um_notifications->api->store_notification( $row, 'new_action', $vars );
    }
}

do_action( 'um_before_profile_fields'); 


trigger_new_notification( $args , $ids ); // Call function and pass $args and $ids as variables
```

Answer (score 0):

I you use one $id as argument of function you may try this:

```
function trigger_new_notification( $id ) {
        global $um_notifications;
        $vars = array(
        "post_title" => get_post_field( 'post_title', $project_id ),
        "photo" => um_get_avatar_url( get_avatar( get_current_user_id(), 40 ) ),
        "member" => um_user('display_name'),
        "notification_uri" => cpm_url_project_details( $project_id )
    );  
  $um_notifications->api->store_notification( $id, 'new_action', $vars );

   }
```

If you try use array of ids av argumt you can try this code:

```
function trigger_new_notification( $ids ) {
        global $um_notifications;

/* Get information about the project */
$vars = array(
    "post_title" => get_post_field( 'post_title', $project_id ),
    "photo" => um_get_avatar_url( get_avatar( get_current_user_id(), 40 ) ),
    "member" => um_user('display_name'),
    "notification_uri" => cpm_url_project_details( $project_id )
);  

/* Send notification to every assaigned user */
foreach($ids as $row)
    {
        $um_notifications->api->store_notification( $row, 'new_action', $vars );
    }


 /* How it should print, where '14' is the user id */
/* $um_notifications->api->store_notification( 14, 'new_action', $vars ); */


}
```

Comment: Tried `function trigger_new_notification( $ids )` but no work :-(

Comment: In `add_action('um_before_profile_fields', 'trigger_new_notification', 100);` 100 is id?

Comment: No,
http://docs.ultimatemember.com/article/53-using-notifications-api-to-add-custom-notifications[link]

Answer (score 0):

@Andreas I agree with you regarding $args. I got the script from http://docs.ultimatemember.com/article/53-using-notifications-api-to-add-custom-notifications

Is this correct? same problem but var_dump now says **string(0) "".**

```
$ids = array_column($users, 'id');


/* #### NOTIFICATION ACTIONS #### */            
add_action('um_before_profile_fields', 'trigger_new_notification', 100);
function trigger_new_notification( $ids ) {
        global $um_notifications;

                um_fetch_user( get_current_user_id() );


/* Get information about the project */
$vars = array(
    "post_title" => get_post_field( 'post_title', GetLastPostId() ),
    "photo" => um_get_avatar_url( get_avatar( get_current_user_id(), 40 ) ),
    "member" => um_user('display_name'),
    "notification_uri" => '/projects/?project_id='.GetLastPostId().'&tab=project&action=index'
);  

$um_notifications->api->store_notification( $ids, 'new_action', $vars );


}

do_action( 'um_before_profile_fields');
```

Comment: See here: https://3v4l.org/jE5QC I had to comment the functions as they can't run on 3v4l. But as you can see I call the function and the function can use $ids and output the userIDs. This is how I think it should be, But with the functions uncommented.

Comment: @Andreas IT WORKS! Thanks! ☺️

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for help with this

```
$um_notifications->api->store_notification(
```

has changed to:

```
UM()->Notifications_API()->api()->store_notification(
```